# css3 form validation - using with CodeIgniter framework (php)

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

I am converting a previous form to html5 with css3 (styling/error message will be done with css and no javascript)
Here is the result I have so far:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/gqgll1fkthj8f8c/html5form.png

**My question :** 
Before I was setting custom display message to my fields in the controllers this way :

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'lang:label_email', 'required|valid_email|is_unique[user.email]');
```

Now I want to remove all this validation from the controller, and move it directly in the html page:

```
<input pattern=".{5,64}" title="<?echo lang('val_5_64_char'); ?>" type="password" required placeholder="<?echo lang('label_password'); ?>" name="password" " id="password" />
```

This way I can still provide custom message, but I don't see how to pass parameters to my label_lang.php file. 
Now I have to have a custom message for each possibility :

```
#VALIDATION (label_lang.php):
$lang['val_5_64_char']  = "Length required [5 - 64]";
```

Is this possible with codeIgniter? From what I see codeIgniter did not adjust to this new validation paradigm and i'm struggling to achieve it. I just started using this framework, thanks for the hand !

Comment: Just to say that I found a way to use parameters :

Comment: <input type="text" pattern=".{1,50}" title="<?echo sprintf(lang('val_x_y_char'), '1', '50'); ?>" required 
   placeholder="<?echo lang('label_last_name'); ?>" name="last_name" " id="last_name" value="<?php echo set_value('last_name'); ?>" />

Comment: #VALIDATION:
$lang['val_x_y_char']  = "Longueur requise : [%s - %s]";

Comment: I had to put the validation both in the html and on the controller in order to prevent older browser from passing validation rules.